# How do I fix the MBR of a dual boot between Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 7?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

Firstly, pardon the chaos. I have an Ubuntu partition that I've shrank in half to install Windows. When I ran Windows and rebooted after updates, there was no boot loader and it automatically chose Windows. I used easyBCD to configure the boot loader and add Ubuntu to the list, but when I tried to boot Ubuntu, I got a blinking white line in the
top left corner of a black screen. I redownloaded easyBCD, moved Windows to the top of the list, rebooted and then the only boot option was Ubuntu, the Windows option didn't even appear. I used Ubuntu to change from the Windows boot manager to GRUB2 and none of the ways I've researched to add Windows to GRUB2 have worked for me. Is my best option to just reinstall Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late response, I ended up deleting both operating systems and using this method: http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony

I would've liked to figure it out but I just didn't have the time. From what I gather, in most dual boot situations, one should have Windows installed first so that it's boot loader doesn't erase GRUB2.

Answer (score 1):

Please add your windows entry from grub.cfg, using grub is always the recommended way.
I would recommend not exploring booting grub from windows loader.